# Debug shared method in REALbasic with gdb or similar tool

Tags: linux, gdb, elf, realbasic, xojo

What I want to do is to debug: break and disassemble function defined in RealBasic language that have following signature: `foo(bs as BinaryStream) as String`. The problem is that it seems that there is no symbol defined. GDB didn't see function named like that when calling `info functions`. Do you know how could i get acces to it by address, or in any other way? Platform is Linux i386.

Comment: You should also mention on which platform you're working. OSX or Linux, because I believe the behaviors are different.

Comment: I am realy sorry, I forgot to write that the platform is Linux i386

Comment: Well, then edit your question and add the information

Comment: @user3446898 What does "dissas" mean in "break and dissas"?

Comment: @sashoalm "dissassembly"